# WooCommerce display taxonomy categories and childcategories on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to show in WooCommerce product page a custom taxonomy called "product_fit" which has the following structure:

```
Car maker (as main parent term)
- Car model (as child term of Car maker)
-- Production year (as child term of Car model)
```

How can I display it on the product page ? 
I did not find any example code.

I try to achieve this form on product page:

```
Ford:
- Focus (2007,2008,2009)
- Mondeo (2009,2010)
Opel:
- Astra (2010,2011)
- Corsa (2009)
```

Comment: is `product_fit` is a product custom taxonomy, a product attribute or a product subcategory? What data is in `product_fit` as you don't specify. Where is your actual code intent? Where you are trying to display that? … Your question **is very unclear** actually. please clarify it.

Comment: Hi, product_fit is a product custom taxonomy and it contains the following data: Car maker (as category parent)
- Car model (as child of Car maker)
-- Production year (as child of Car model). I’m trying to display this information on the single product page.

Comment: **Where exactly on the single product page?** … Note that your custom taxonomy contains child/parent terms and not categories, so it's **hierarchical** just as woocommerce product_cat taxonomy (default WooCommerce categories)…

Comment: Yes! It’s hierarchical like product_cat taxonomy, I’m trying  to display those informations in a custom product tab

Comment: So please provide the code of this custom tab with your additional code intent…